# Error using geom_join to join nearest coordinate data

Tags: r, coordinates, spatial-join, weather, county

I am currently trying to join weather data from NOAA dataset that I have acquired to a county census data set. This is necessary because the NOAA data is given by Weather station and not by town, county, or state. I have found a key online that gives geographical coordinates of each weather station (https://data.giss.nasa.gov/gistemp/station_data_v4/station_list.txt). I also have acquired a key that gives me the centroid geographical coordinates of each US county (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/User:Michael_J/County_table). I am now trying to join the county centroids to the nearest weather station coordinates. I have found that the geo_join functions in both tigris and fuzzyjoin packages in R may be capable of doing this. From what I've found so far, fuzzyjoin's geo_join function seemed to be better designed for this join. However when I run the following code I get the following error:

Code run:

```
WeatherCounty <- Centroids %>% geo_left_join(Weather, by = c("Latitude" = "Lat", "Longitude" = "Lon"), method = "haversine")
```

Result:
Error in if (sum(m) == 0) { : missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed

My instinct here was to use the geo_join function as if it follows the syntax of an ordinary join in dplyr. I doubt that is correct, but am not able to understand how the syntax in geo_join documentation online is able to identify the correct latitude and longitude coordinates from the dataset.

How can I use this function or perhaps another way of achieving this goal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Having coordinates you may build simple features (`sf`) objects in R, and then use spatial functions (`geo_join` just considers coordinates as *strings* and compares them). A spatial function we may use is `st_join` which passes attributes from one dataframe to another based on spatial predicates, in this case I'm using nearest neighbor, or `st_nn`

```r
library(sf)
library(fuzzyjoin)
library(rvest)
library(janitor)
library(dplyr)
library(nngeo)

# READ FILES FROM INTERNET
wiki = read_html("https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/User:Michael_J/County_table") |> 
  html_node("table") |> html_table() |> janitor::clean_names() 
wiki = wiki |> mutate(latitude = gsub("°|+", "", latitude), longitude = gsub("°|–", "", longitude)) |>  # that – is not a minus sign 
  select(4,5, latitude, longitude) |>
  mutate(latitude = as.numeric(latitude), longitude = -as.numeric(longitude))
met = read.fwf("https://data.giss.nasa.gov/gistemp/station_data_v4/station_list.txt", widths = c(12, 32, 9, 10, 4), skip = 1, header = F)
names(met) = c("id", "station", "lat", "lon", "bi") # fwf reading is a bit cumbersome, just read enough for your example


# MAKE SF OBJECTS
wiki = wiki |>   st_as_sf( coords = c("longitude", "latitude")) |> st_set_crs(4326)
met = met |> st_as_sf(coords = c("lon", "lat")) |> st_set_crs(4326)

# use st_join with nearest_neighbors
joined = st_join(wiki[1:100,], met[1:100,], join = st_nn, k = 1)

# print the joined object
joined
# Simple feature collection with 100 features and 5 fields
# Geometry type: POINT
# Dimension:     XY
# Bounding box:  xmin: -178.3388 ymin: 30.65922 xmax: -85.18698 ymax: 69.44934
# Geodetic CRS:  WGS 84
# # A tibble: 100 × 6
# county_2 county_seat_s_3             geometry id             station                               bi
# * <chr>    <chr>                    <POINT [°]> <chr>          <chr>                              <int>
#   1 Autauga  Prattville      (-86.64449 32.53638) "USW00053864 " "Alabaster Shelby Co Ap          "     1
# 2 Baldwin  Bay Minette     (-87.74607 30.65922) "USW00053864 " "Alabaster Shelby Co Ap          "     1
# 3 Barbour  Clayton         (-85.40546 31.87067) "USW00053864 " "Alabaster Shelby Co Ap          "     1
# 4 Bibb     Centreville     (-87.12715 33.01589) "USW00053864 " "Alabaster Shelby Co Ap          "     1
# 5 Blount   Oneonta         (-86.56725 33.97745) "USW00053864 " "Alabaster Shelby Co Ap          "     1
```

Comment: Thank You this worked very well.

Comment: If the answer was helpful please upvote or mark as accepted answer accordingly